# Custom JSON Serialize with custom mapping C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to serialize/deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": {
        "ID": 1,
        "TITLE": "Example",
        "ARRAY": [
            {
                "Item1": "Result1",
                "Item2": "Result2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried with the following class format, but no sucess yet... Can someone help me deserialize it?

```
public class myClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TITLE")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

obs.: Using the namespace `Newtonsoft.JSON`

Comment: You can just head over to http://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json in and it will generate the class for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example class definition above, you have called the class `myClass` but you would have had to call it `result` because `ID` and `TITLE` are members of the `result` JSON in the given example. `myClass` would not resolve to anything.

I don't know why you'd want to have a property called `Name` that is mapped to `TITLE`, but ok, if you want to do that you can modify the solution after you get it working.

Still, we're not done yet. You also have a JSON member called `ARRAY` and you need to define a separate class for that.

And still there is an additional problem: the `result` JSON is nested inside an implicit base object, so we need to define that as well. Let's call it `BaseResult`.

```
public class ARRAY
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public List<ARRAY> ARRAY { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResult
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can copy your JSON and paste it in any *.cs file with `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`. It will generate POCO objects representing your JSON, which in your case will be this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public ARRAY[] ARRAY { get; set; }
}

public class ARRAY
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, asuming that you have your JSON in a string variable named `data`, you can deserialize it as follows:

```
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);
```